# List of names depending on another field in object

Tags: javascript, json, lodash

I have a object of items where I need to get all the names depending on the value of another field.

Example of one object:

```
items: [
{
url: "https://...",
id: "1693",
type: "ABC",
currencyCode: "SEK",
longName: "Abc",
name: "ABC",
micCode: "DEF",
listingDate: "2018-05-25T00:00:00+02:00",
subType: "STOCK",
}
```

I can get all the names with (after iteration of id):

```
var name = _.pick(dataArray[i], ['name']);
```

but I need to get all the names only where subType: 'STOCK'.

How do I do this?

Comment: [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `filter` before using the `_.pick` method

```js
const items = [
{
 url: "https://...",
 id: "1693",
 type: "ABC",
 currencyCode: "SEK",
 longName: "Abc",
 name: "ABC",
 micCode: "DEF",
 listingDate: "2018-05-25T00:00:00+02:00",
 subType: "STOCK",
},
{
 url: "https://...",
 id: "1693",
 type: "ABC",
 currencyCode: "SEK",
 longName: "Abc",
 name: "ABCD",
 micCode: "DEF",
 listingDate: "2018-05-25T00:00:00+02:00",
 subType: "NOTSTOCK",
},
{
 url: "https://...",
 id: "1693",
 type: "ABC",
 currencyCode: "SEK",
 longName: "Abc",
 name: "ABCGFD",
 micCode: "DEF",
 listingDate: "2018-05-25T00:00:00+02:00",
 subType: "STOCK",
},

]

console.log(items.filter(item => item.subType === 'STOCK'));
```